# Invoking Webservice client from Java through jar file

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

We have requirement to invoke webservice from Java. I tried with JAX-WS through netbeans, but it created war file. Problem with war file is that we require additional server for deployment. 
Is there any other way in which we can create webservice client in Java and create jar file instead of war.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a JAX-WS web service client in NetBeans you need to point it to a WSDL that describes the service. It sounds like you're accidentally creating a web service server...

Comment: Hi, I have created webservice in ext application and I'm invoking it through Java. My only problem is when I create it in Netbeans. IT is creating war file and deploying it in glassfish server. Is there any way I can have this to be done with jar file instead of war.

Comment: @user3072980 you must be creating the wrong kind of project. Just create a normal Java project then create a new web service client and copy/paste in the WSDL path of your external application. See also https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html